# Send form when hitting enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form in a jQuery enabled site. The form does not feature an `<input type="submit">` button. For that reason, it's not submitted when you hit *enter*. What's the recommended way to emulate such behaviour?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(function(){
    $("form input:first").focus();
});
//--></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="user">
<input type="password" name="pass">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

### Update

I'm just trying to add a quick simple improvement to an existing form. I fully understand all the concerns about accessibility but the app itself needs JavaScript and will not run at all without it. A fallback to submit the form would be of little use.

Comment: Probably not a requirement, but how would you submit this form via a mobile device?

Comment: You need to use a submit button/image

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put a submit button in the form, and make it invisible using JavaScript. This fulfils 2 purposes:

1. The enter button will work because there **is** a submit button present
2. Non-javascript users will be able to use your form

Comment: I think this is a better solution than keypress checking, as you can add new controls without having to wire every single one into a javascript keypress checking function. In addition, some controls may not behave properly, such as someone who uses the keyboard to select an item in a dropdown, when they press enter to select it, it may submit the form.

Comment: It's pretty elegant indeed: `$("form input[type=submit]").hide();` and you're done.

Comment: What about just hiding the button by CSS? Hiding by javascript may cause visible artifact in IE due to slow execution speed of JS.

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't hide the button at all. Much better for people to see an explicit way to submit a form, and there are **plenty** of people who don't understand the concept of pressing enter in a form field. But you're right, if you're going to hide it you might as well do it with plain CSS as there's no specific reason it should be there without javascript and hidden with javascript

Comment: Oops... It looks like IE8 ignores hidden submit buttons :(

Comment: IE-resistant hidden button: `<div style="width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;"><input type="submit" value="Entrar"></div>`

Answer (score 4):

I would capture the keypress event of the input elements, watch for a keycode of 13 (enter) and call submit. Like so:

```
$("form input").keypress(function(ev){
    if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
        $("form")[0].submit();
    }
});
```

This code is untested.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just feature a button that is hidden using CSS, or even better JS: in that case the form will remain accessible to people that have JS disabled, and you should get your enter automatically

Comment: Yes, hidden buttons seem to work (you always have to test yourself this kind of stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery form plugin.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 1):

Recommended? I'm not sure it's recommended to emulate this behaviour at all!

Whilst you can mess around with trying to detect `keypress` for Enter, there are some subtle browser differences about how Enter presses are supposed to work which won't be quite the same as what you produce. And your form will fail to work at all without JavaScript, which isn't ideal.

So put a submit button in. If you're really adamant that the button shouldn't appear on-page (and I'm not sure that's a good idea), you can always absolute-position it off the left-hand side of the page where no-one can see it.

Note that WebKit will submit the form anyway despite the lack of button. If you must patch this up with messy script, make sure you cancel the default action for the keypress or you may get double-submission.

Answer (score 1):

Safari, Firefox, Opera, and IE8 all **do submit** the form when you **hit enter in text input field**. Neither is submit button nor javascript needed. [Try yourself](http://jaakko.kapsi.fi/tmp/formsubmit.html).

(Didn't test IE6/7 but I'm 95% sure they do too.)

I agree with other that capturing the enter is not good idea.

**Update**: the above is true, except that Firefox does **not** submit a form containing password field and having no submit button. No idea why, can anyone see a reason behind that?

**Update 2**: ... and except for IE, if there's only one input field.

Comment: Curious. It seems to be that way when there's only *one* field.

Comment: Number of fields doesn't matter, but password field seems to be special for Firefox. I wonder if that's a bug.

Comment: Buttonless forms with only one input field will not be submitted by enter in MSIE.

Comment: BalusC, thanks. I have always used enter key for submitting forms (whether submit button existed or not) and assumed that was standard behavior in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I used following thing for the same purpose but not for jquery try this may help you.

```
function submitenter(myfield,e)
  {
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e) keycode = e.which;
    else return true;

    if (keycode == 13)
    {
        myfield.form.onsubmit();
        return false;
    }
    else
     return true;
  }
```